# My published Expo App on Google Play still installs an old version

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play-console

I uploaded a new version of my app developed with Expo to Google Play, but when users install it, it starts with the old version first and updates afterwards, while users are running it.How can I make it install the latest version? I need to mention that a deleted the previous apk in Google Play console, and it remains only one, the latest. Thank you.

Comment: would love to know as well

Comment: What did you end up doing in the end to get the latest version out on the store? @sunviwo?